# Accessing ironkey from command-line Linux system

Tags: linux, permissions, usb-flash-drive, slackware, scsi

So, [this USB-key device](http://www.kingston.com/us/usb/encrypted_security/IKS1000) (which registers as a CD-ROM / SCSI-device; weird, I know), which ships with a read-only partition (kinda?) including a Linux binary you need to execute to access to the data-partitions. Unfortunately, I can't get the binary to execute:

```
# /mnt/cdrom/linux/ironkey
-bash: /mnt/cdrom/linux/ironkey: No such file or directory
```

I tried some of the obvious stuff, first:

```
# cp !$ /root/
# chmod +x /root/ironkey
# /root/ironkey
-bash: /root/ironkey: No such file or directory
# file /root/ironkey
ironkey: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

So, I've got an executable file, copied off of the fake CD-ROM; and I *still* can't exec it? Does anybody know what next-steps I can take to get this executing?

> - OS: **Slackware 14.1**
> - Drive: **Ironkey Basic S250**
> - Machine: **Acer E3-111 (C0WA)**

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it turns out that 64-bit Slackware doesn't ship with multilib support, and thus can't run 32-bit programs.

Although it's not something I can use, unfortunately, due to this being an ancient, offline machine, I *did* find this resource for allowing 64-bit Slackware to run 32-bit programs. Here's hoping this helps somebody out, down the line:

> **http://www.slackware.com/~alien/multilib/**